# How to sequence of MFCC coefficients vectors for speaker recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, svm

The project is to use SVM for speaker recognition using MFCC as a feature set. Usually MFCC coefficients are created with a window size in terms of mill second. However, since a speaker speaks for few seconds at least one can use a sequence of MFCC in SVM. The question is how it can be done. Generally, SVM or any kernel takes a vector as an input, but in this case we can use several vectors or matrix to increase robustness. How SVM can learn matrices rather them vectors?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/56429/5874, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55504189/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional approach is to use specialized mathematical model to analyze factors in MFCC sequence and extract the speaker vector. You drop the variability in the MFCC related to actual words, you drop the variability related to intonation and leave just the factor related to the speaker. The speaker vector can be later analyzed with SVM. You can check details from [i-vector tutorial](https://people.csail.mit.edu/sshum/talks/ivector_tutorial_interspeech_27Aug2011.pdf).

More advanced research uses neural network to extract speaker vectors, so-called [d-vectors](https://github.com/rajathkmp/speaker-verification).

Then you use SVM to classify d-vectors.

Comment: > Homomorphism

This is not really reasonable because speech text contains other information except speaker identity

> I need some ways to verify my results. 

Download voxceleb dataset and demonstrate the superiority of your method